# What things must international students take care of while writing a Masters SoP for a US drama school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, statement-of-purpose, international-students

I am only looking for tips on how to best direct my SoP in the right direction so as to not digress and stay on point with my material.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the SoP is any different here than for the general case. It is a statement of what you want to achieve in the degree program and what your longer term goals are.

In particular, it isn't a statement about your skills and past accomplishments. Use the CV and letters of recommendation for that. Note that letters of recommendation are relatively important in US admissions.

If you intend to specialize in some aspect of your field (in the program and later) then say some things about that. But this is the same for everyone.